# Problems configuring blowfish_secret on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having some issues with this message I have tried everything that Google suggested, but this message will not go away:

> The configuration file now needs a secret passphrase (blowfish_secret).

I am running this under Windows, but unfortunately I have tried everything I can in my power to fix this error. All honesty here I am getting quite frustrated with this and I set the right perimeters I have prove here to show you what I did.

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ‘aBrh#Rr9#oJFe@%@gVvIurRq30NqMW8O@bf+O4Slg8ZHy‘; /* YOU NEED FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */
```

But, yet it's still not working like it says I have restarted both MySQL, and Apache lots of times, and still get this message. I also, tried to clear cookies and history in my browser, but yet I still get the same error I am out of ideas how to fix this error.

Can someone please help me fix this problem?

Comment: It would also help if you could please add any php errors that are being generated.

Comment: Do you really have "smart quotes" around your value? If so, those might be your problem.

Comment: I am trying find that now give me a few please.

Comment: Um, I don't know where that would be I am lost would that be in the apache logs?

Comment: And, there is no smart quotes at all.

Comment: Is there a easier way of contacting you? I don't think the comments are coming through to you.

Comment: I am just going to say heck with it and install wamp instead and fix all issues than.